# Grouped_collection_select Rails 4 problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a problem with grouped collection select.

```html
<%= f.collection_select :id, RequestType.order(:typeName), :id, 
                        :typeName,include_blank:true %>

<%= f.grouped_collection_select :id, RequestType.order(:typeName), 
                  :RequestSubTypes, :typeName, :RequestType_id, :typeName, 
                  include_blank:true %>
```

Here are my models

```html
class RequestSubType < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :RequestType
end
```

```html
class RequestType < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :RequestSubTypes
end
```

And in my request_sub_types table i have

```html
t.integer  "RequestType_id"
```

for referencing RequestType model.
I have a problem telling :

```html
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: 
request_sub_types.request_type_id: SELECT "request_sub_types".* FROM  
"request_sub_types" WHERE "request_sub_types"."request_type_id" = ?
```

I am doing this one with tutorial from RailsCast.

Comment: `RequestType_id` is totally wrong.It is supposed to be `request_type_id`

Comment: @Pavan, you mean that i must remigrate my db with request_type_id field?

Comment: Yes.Do the rollback and re migrate with `request_type_id` And also there are some mistakes in the code.. i will be explaining those in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this line which is totally wrong.

```
<%= f.grouped_collection_select :id, RequestType.order(:typeName), 
                  :RequestSubTypes, :typeName, :RequestType_id, :typeName, 
                  include_blank:true %>
```

**Mistake #1**

*Model class name* should be **singular**,not **plural** i.e, **`RequestSubType`** not **`RequestSubTypes`**

**Mistake #2**

*Model class names* cannot be used as **`symbols`**

```
:RequestSubTypes  #wrong
```

**Mistake #3**

*Field names or attributes* should be in [**snake_case**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) i.e, **`request_type_id`** not **`RequestType_id`**

Run a `rake db:rollback` of your migration which contained `RequestType_id`.Change it to `request_type_id` and then do `rake db:migrate`